# Can a function defined in a bookmarklet be called from a page-level script?

Tags: javascript, permissions, popup, wrapper, bookmarklet

I have a bookmarklet that needs to open a new window/tab.  In order to avoid the popup blocker, I need to call the `window.open()` method directly in the bookmarklet ie: at the browser-level.

However, I want to keep the bookmarklet updatable by loading external Javascript files. To do this, the bookmarklet needs to append script nodes to the DOM.  If i were to put `window.open()` code in one of these externally loaded scripts, the popup blocker would block it since its page-level.

What I want to know is if I can create a wrapper function around `window.open()` in my bookmarklet, then call it from the externally loaded script?  What is the scope and what are the permissions on a wrap such as this?

Comment: Would it be possible to `window.open()` with a name, then inject stuff into that window later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution which isn't perfect but meets the requirements:

Here is the bookmarklet code:

```
javascript:window.open(window.location);window.location="http://www.google.com/";var%20s=document.createElement('script');s.setAttribute('src','http://my-script.js');document.body.appendChild(s);void(0);
```

The readable step-by-step equivalent being:

```
window.open(window.location);                // Clone the current tab
window.location = "http://www.google.com/";  // Navigate to the desired page url
var s = document.createElement('script');    // Create the script
s.setAttribute('src','http://my-script.js'); //
document.body.appendChild(s);                // Embed it into current document
```

Only one issue remains: the page you want to show isn't active by default. The cloned one is.

Answer (score 0):

I wondered if that approach might work - good to see that it does.

The general problem here is that browsers will not let you open a new window other than by direct user interaction. So you cannot open the window from a remote script.

You are opening the window directly from the bookmarklet, moving to that location and then invoking the remote script.

The alternative, which I went with, was to move the contents of the remote script directly to the bookmarklet. That was fine for my simple application. I wrote up that [on my blog](http://craiccomputing.blogspot.com/2011/02/javascript-bookmarklet-that-can-create.html)